# Add run-time information to CocoaHTTPServer using custom Response class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, http, cocoaasyncsocket

I have the following code to start my own [Cocoa HTTP Server](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer). In order to manually handle the responses I have created my custom `HTTPConnection` class named `PictureHTTPConnection`

```
self.httpServer = [[HTTPServer alloc]init];
self.httpServer.type = @"_http._tcp.";
self.httpServer.name = @"MyBonjour Name";
self.httpServer.connectionClass = [PictureHTTPConnection class];
```

The problem here is that the `PictureHTTPConnection` class needs some information in order to handle the HTTP connections. However, I only provide the class and therefore I don't have a reference to the instance. I could do something with global data but this is not very good programming practise.

The best way I can think of is setting the `PictureHTTPConnection`'s delegate to the `UIApplicationDelegate` so that it can answer any callbacks. :-(

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer/issues/5) for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same exact problem. To solve this, I changed the code of the `HTTPServer` class so that you can set it a `delegate` that will in turn be set on each `HTTPConnection` created. When the `HTTPConnection` has to handle the request I call the delegate. This is far from clean as well and I was seeking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get callbacks by adding a category to HTTPServer that gets & sets a delegate. `objc_setAssociatedObject` is your friend here:

```
@interface HTTPServer (WithDelegate)
    @property (strong, nonatomic) id delegate;
@end

@implementation HTTPServer (WithDelegate)
    NSString const *key = @"HttpServer.WithDelegate.key";
    - (void)setDelegate:(id)delegate
    {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &key, delegate, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    }
    - (id)delegate
    {
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &key);
    }
@end
```

Set the delegate when you initialize the HTTPServer instance (or whenever). Call methods on it from your custom HTTPConnection implementation like this:

```
[config.server.delegate handleRequest:theRequest];
```

You must implement `handleRequest:(Whatever*)theRequest` in your delegate class